# Sharepoint: Any way to get lookup list's other column's value?

Tags: sharepoint, lookup

let's say, I've create 2 splist, one is 'student_course', another is 'student'.
the student_course contains a lookup field "student_id" of student.

is there any way i can display all the student information which is under course of "computer science"?

Thanks in advance for whoever trying to help. =)

Answer (score 2):

In SharePoint 2010 it comes out of the box, it's easier to upgrade then to develop a custom field

Answer (score 1):

In SharePoint 2010 you can just select the other columns from the list from which you are pulling the lookup column. See below...

[image: SharePoint 2010 Edit Column Settings Screen]

You are limited in the types of data you can pull in from other columns in the lookup list. Those limitations can be found in [this MS SharePoint article](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/create-list-relationships-by-using-unique-and-lookup-columns-HA101729901.aspx#_Toc270607415) and are essentially that you can only pull:

- Single Line of Text
- Number
- Date and Time

All of the other column types cannot be pulled in via a lookup.